# Javascript ES6(ES2015)/ Typescript: how to access local method inside static method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I basically want to access the "foo2" method inside a static "bar" method, but so far I only able access "foo1" and "foo3" method only. Can anyone teach me how can I access the non static foo2 method.

```
let foo1 = () => {
    alert('foo1’);
  };

class ABC extends Component {

  static bar() {
      foo1(); //can work

      foo2; //not work with error "Can't find variable foo2"

      foo2(); //not work with error "Can't find variable foo2"

      this.foo2(); //not work with error "this.foo2 is not a function"

      this.foo2; //no error but no alert, basically nothing happen

      ABC.foo3() //can work
  }

  foo2 = () => {
      alert('foo2');
  };

  static foo3 = () => {
      alert('foo3');
  };

}

module.exports = ABC;
```

Comment: do you use typescript or just javascript?

Comment: I think you can not use arrow function as class method.

Comment: This is impossible; explaining why you need it, with a real example, will enable us to offer alternatives.

Comment: @KonstantinVitkovsky Actually the reason I want to do this is because I want to override the react native router flux right button function, so that I can call reload for the webview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524030/react-native-router-flux-override-left-or-right-button-inside-component-and-acc

Comment: @Newbie009 ok, but the question is applicable for any js/ts app :-) btw did my answer helped you, or is there anything else to solve?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING: accessing instance-methods from static-methods is not desired, it might confuse other developers. Try to avoid using it. If you do use it - make sure your code is well commented and explains how does it work.**

What you want to do is to bind the static method with context of the object which method you want to invoke from static method. You can do this by invoking it with `call` method:

```
class ABC extends Component {
    static bar () {
      this.foo();
    }
    foo () {
      // function body
    }
}

let instance = new ABC();
ABC.bar.call(instance);
```

or using `bind` if you want to pass the function like callback, etc, *pre-bind* it, so to speak:

```
let instance = new ABC();
setTimeout(ABC.bar.bind(instance), 1000);
```

**NOTE:** `this` by default references your class, not instance of the class (it will reference an instance after we bind it), so if you want to call another static method from the first static method you want to use full class name.

```
static bar () {
  this.foo();
  ABC.someOtherStaticMethod();
}
```

**ALSO NOTE:** if you use Typescript you will get an error when referencing instance-method, because `this` in your static method by default reference your class. To work-around this you might want cast this's type to `any`:

```
static bar () {
  (<any>this).foo();
}
```

Here you tell Typescript compiler something like "presume that `this` is not our class but something we don't know" just to get rid of error on compile time.

Comment: You explained what you could do, but you'd still have to get a hold of the instance variable to make this work, which the OP does not. As much as it technically answers the question, if the OP does find a way to grab a reference to `this`, your suggestion would make the code flow be the opposite of what devs expect and confuse them, especially with the typecasting to `any`.

Comment: I do agree, this approach is a work-around and it may be ugly and it may confuse other developers, but sometimes you have to make _something_ to make things work. In the end all that matters is making the software that works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can never access instance methods from a static method (in any language). There is only one static method, but multiple instances, how would it know which instance (`this`) to use?